# SQLite:"ALTER TABLE `game` ADD UNIQUE(`name`)" Error in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I used the same command syntax above as in Mysql  and would like set a unique key for the tables's filed on Android Device environment, however, the error prompted in LogCat:

> 03-23 16:16:45.580: E/Database(657): Failure 1 (near "UNIQUE": syntax
>   error) on 0x2c0240 when preparing 'ALTER TABLE `game` ADD
>   UNIQUE(`name`);'.

Checking the SQLite's doc, it seems that SQLite does not use this way for setting a unique key. Does anyboy know to do it ? Thanks for response inadvance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can column constraints be altered after creation in SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079608/can-column-constraints-be-altered-after-creation-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

sqlite support alter in another way.
You can try the following:
   `create unique index unique_name on game(name);`
If you want to create a constraint for two or more columns at one time:
   `create unique index unique_name on game(name1,name2,mame3);`

Comment: that's not what the docs say