# Can column constraints be altered after creation in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

Say I have created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1(column_1 UNIQUE, column_2 NOT NULL);
```

Now after I have inserted lots of data, for some reason I need to remove UNIQUE constraint from the first column, that's column_1. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite's [ALTER TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) does not support this.

Your best bet is to export the database as text (`.dump` in the `sqlite3` tool), remove the `UNIQUE` constrant, and recreate the database.

Answer (score 6):

`ALTER TABLE` in [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) is very limited.

You can however, to a limited extent, change some contraints using `CREATE INDEX` and `CREATE TRIGGER`.

You could, eg:

```
CREATE TABLE table_1(column_1, column_2);
-- No constrains in table_1
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t1_c1_1 ON table_1 (column_1);
-- From now, column_1 must be UNIQUE
CREATE TRIGGER t1_c2_1i BEFORE INSERT ON table_1 WHEN column_2 IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'column_2 can not be NULL');
END;
CREATE TRIGGER t1_c2_1u BEFORE UPDATE ON table_1 WHEN column_2 IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'column_2 can not be NULL');
END;
-- From now, NULL column_2 update/insert will fail
DROP TRIGGER t1_c1_1;
-- Now column_1 doesn't need to be UNIQUE
DROP TRIGGER t1_c2_1i;
DROP TRIGGER t1_c2_1u;
-- Now column_2 may be NULL
```

Note:

- you can't delete existing constrains;
- creating indexes will grow your data (index data);
- creating trigger may degrade table performance.

Another workaround is duplicating existing table removing constraints:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE table_1 AS SELECT * FROM MAIN.table_1;
DROP TABLE table_1;
CREATE TABLE table_1 AS SELECT * FROM TEMP.table1;
-- table_1 is now a copy from initial table_1, but without constraints
```